# iMac Thunderbolt Firmware Issues

Tags: macos, imac, thunderbolt, firmware

I am running High Sierra and am trying to use an Antelope Orion 32+ with this system through Thunderbolt. The device gets picked up in my system info and the port is in use.

It is impossible for this device to make a connection with the supplied software of the manufacturer of the device. I've had contact with their support and they told me it is an issue of the 2011 iMac12,2 Thunderbolt firmware. Everything seems to be up to date.

- Thunderbolt firmware version 25.1
- Port micro firmwareversion 2.1.3

Since this iMac from 2011 is using Thunderbolt v1 but also revisions of this Thunderbolt v1 have been used in newer Macs, only the 2011 Macs have this problem. I don't know where to look anymore.

Did I maybe skip some Thunderbolt firmware updates in the past? Could this explain why it is not working?